# ASP.NET unable to connect to Oracle after publishing Visual Studio .NET code using ODP.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, vb.net, visual-studio, odp.net

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. I can connect to the Oracle database using ODP.net with my Visual Studio 2022 .NET application before I publish the application to IIS. I can connect to the database while developing and testing the code in Visual Studio.

However, once I publish the application on the same machine, I get an error. After I published the ASP.NET application to IIS, I get

> ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I'm using ODP.net managed driver to connect to the database.
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, Version=4.122

My Oracle client is 21c (64 bit)

Comment: Where is your `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: Good Question. My tnsnames.ora file is in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory. Also the TNS_ADMIN environment variable is set to that directory.  Thanks

Comment: Below is the dbconnect code in VB.net:   
 string user = "dbuser";
 string pwd = "password";
string db = "dbalias-in-tnsnames.ora file";
string conStringUser = "User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + pwd + ";Data Source=" + db + ";" +
"Pooling = true; Min Pool Size = 5; Max Pool Size = 10;";

Comment: It doesn't look like IIS is using my Windows account when running the VB.net code. Would you know what the default Windows user account it's using on my desktop?

Comment: Check if your `TNS_ADMIN` is set as system environment variable. If it is set as user environment variable then it does not work on IIS.

Comment: I checked System Properties->Environment Variables; looked at the Systems variables and it's set. I also added the TNS_ADMIN variable to User variables so it's in both places. However I get the same results.

Comment: Have a look at your configuration file `<your application.exe.config>` and/or `machine.config`, `web.config`. It could be defined also there. See [Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8159)

Comment: I added the following to the Web.config file;the same error: -
<configSections>
  <section name="new.oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=*, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
<new.oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
 <version number="*">
  <settings>
   <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\app\Oracle21_64\product\21.0.0\client_1\network\admin"/>
  </settings>
  <!--Oracle configuration settings-->
</new.oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

Comment: Adding the TNS_ADMIN to my webconfig resolved my problem. Thank you